# Looking for an unofficial Sonic game

Tags: game-identification, sonic-the-hedgehog-series

I remember playing one unofficial (i.e. not affiliated with Sega) Sonic game as a kid on Windows, but I can't find it any more. However, I've recovered a screenshot of it (I hope it is it).

[image: Sonic]

Anyone knows which game this screenshot is from?

Comment: It's hard to say from this screenshot alone.  The background is ripped directly from Sonic 3's Ice Cap zone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The screenshot is from Ultimate Sonichaos and the game I was looking for is Legendary Sonichaos, both by Magicgrafx...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [*Sonic: After the Sequel*](https://sites.google.com/site/sonicbtsbooth/)? from [this article](http://www.redbull.com/en/games/stories/1331640498401/the-fan-made-sonic-trilogy-you-have-to-play).

Otherwise there is another Sonic game called *Sonic Dimensions* (I couldn't find a link for it you'll have to search).

Hopefully you'll find it among one of those, since one of the games is a trilogy.

There's also an old "hacked" version of a Sonic game that makes you play with some characters in a different way... But I truly can't remember, this was the best I could find. You can also check out this [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL982DFD21EF16B986) of unofficial sonic games.

Comment: I don't think it's among them.

Comment: I have done some extensive research, even used "google the image" option but nothing came up. Sorry :( That's the best I could do.

Comment: Thanks for effort and don't be sad, I've already found it... I hope. ☺